# PLP feature extraction from a signal

Tags: c++, signal-processing, spectrogram

I am wondering if anyone knows how to calculate the PLP(Perpetual Linear Prediction) features of an audio input. I am looking for two things:

1. there is severe lack of good documentation that may explain what and how exactly these features are calculated. So I'd appreciate if anyone can point me towards a documentation maybe?
2. Any c++ code snippet that shows the implementation maybe?

Comment: Did you mean Perceptual Linear Prediction?

Comment: yes that's what I meant

Comment: Search for "perceptual linear prediction feature extraction" offers a number of technical papers, lecture slides and open source software. Could you clarify what you are having difficulty with?